# Garbled Display when installing from Ubuntu LiveUSB onto Dell/Alienware R8 with advanced nVidia card

Tags: ubuntu, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, livecd, nvidia-rtx

I am trying to install `18.0.4` on a `Dell/Alienware R8`. Great machine.

Following are completed:

- Created a new `Boot Entry` for the `LiveUSB`
- Restarted computer and through GRUB selected `Install Ubuntu`
- Was able to view a completely messed up video output:

[image]

The box has a high end `nvidia rtx 2070` card.  The monitor is connected to the hdmi output of the card.

What should I do here?   Note that my only intent on this system is to use the `gpu` for deep learning. ZERO gaming and only very basic X11 graphics needed - just enough to run an IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using `unetbootin` but switched to `etcher`.  In addition on `grub menu` I selected `Safe Graphics`.  Now  I'm in the gui installer. Things are looking up!

Comment: Thank you! I had the same problem (on Dell G5/rtx2070), installing Ubuntu 20.04 from a USB stick. During boot up, I "edited" the "install ubuntu" option, and added `nomodeset` to the list of parameters passed to `linux`, and it worked.